# In memory file system limit cannot be more than JVM max heap size

Tags: coldfusion, commandbox

I started a ColdFusion 11 instance using Commandbox. I wanted to alter a setting in the CFADMIN under `Server Settings` => `Settings`; namely
`Maximum number of POST request parameters`.

I keep getting the error `In memory file system limit cannot be more than JVM max heap size`.

How can I quickly get rid of this error as it has nothing to do with the setting  I want to modify?
I uncheck `Enable In-Memory File System` but this changes nothing.
I set `Memory Limit for In-Memory Virtual File System`  to `1` and get the errore message `In-Memory File System limit per Application must be numeric, less than In-Memory Virtual File System memory limit, and greater than or equal to 1.`

To set my parameter I eventually used `cfconfig set postParametersLimit=1000`.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you on?

Comment: Never heard of the in-memory virtual file system impacting the max number of post requests. I wonder if it is a bug in CommndBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a bug in Adobe ColdFusion because CommandBox doesn't set a max heap size by default!  it's just whatever your OS wants to give it.  Try setting an explicit max in CommandBox.

https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/embedded-server/configuring-your-server/jvm-args#heapsize

Also, FWIW, I'm not sure if the max post size works on a J2E install of CF. It may rely on their hacked up Tomcat version so you may want to test.

Comment: I can confirm it being a bug in ACF. I also get the error message on CF10, having a modified `jvm.config`. Not related to CommandBox at all.

Answer (score 0):

From your own question [its not clear that this is the solution]

Install cfconfig [https://cfconfig.ortusbooks.com/using-the-cli/installation].

Then

```
cfconfig set postParametersLimit=1000
```

Or whatever number you need.

From

https://cfconfig.ortusbooks.com/the-basics/config-items

```
// Maximum number of parameters in a POST request sent to the server.
name='postParametersLimit' type='numeric'
// Limits the amount of data in MB that can be posted to the server in a single request.
name='postSizeLimit' type='numeric'
```